# Append content inside UL with list item and anchor tag <li><a></a></li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-data

How to append content to UL with LIST ITEM and ANCHOR TAG inside it using Javascript?
At the moment I am doing this.

```
    for( var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
    $('<li><a href="#"></a></li>', {
        text: projects[i].author
    }).appendTo('#contributors');
}
```

I can get it to work if I only use `<li></li>` but as soon as I add anchor tags `<li><a href="#"></a></li>` the code does not give a desired result. What would be your solution tot his?

Comment: I want to have a list of items such as this <li><a href="#">CONTENT</a></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the `a` element is being created, so that the `text` and `href` attributes are applied to it. Then it's wrapped in an `li`, and using `parent()` to grab that `li`, is appended to the `#contributors` element.

```
for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
    $('<a />', {
        href: '#',
        text: projects[i].author
    }).wrap('<li />').parent().appendTo('#contributors');
}
```